# Horizontal space in lists

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

What is the best way to change the amount of horizontal space in list environments?

Examples:

```
1.############################ % Near the enumerated item - compacted horizontal space
  ############################

2.############################
  ############################

3.############################
  ############################
```

and

```
1.     ############################ % Far from the enumerated item - stretched horizontal space
       ############################

2.     ############################
       ############################

3.     ############################
       ############################
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust all list parameters easily using the `enumitem` package. For the example you give, the relevant parameter is the `labelsep` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=5em]
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

For other parameters, check the documentation or look for other questions on the site that use the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 6):

Without using any package, you can use `list` as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\begin{list}{\stepcounter{enumi}Problem \arabic{enumi}:\ }
{
\setlength{\labelwidth}{2cm}
\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{3cm}
}
   \item \lipsum[2]
   \item \lipsum[3]
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, but if you want all lists to have the same format, this kind of solution gets tedious quite quickly.

Comment: @Alan: Just define a new common environment, namely `mylist`. :-) Depending on the scenario we want, we might need to reset the counter.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but then your document parts aren't very portable. There are advantages to keeping standard environments.