# Control start point of nested list

Tags: spacing, lists, nesting

After stretching the list horizontally according to [Horizontal space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24712/horizontal-space-in-lists), I've encountered a problem where the nested list items start too deep inside. How can I pull it back to the left where the parent item description starts?

```
1.    ############################
      ############################
          A. Nested item A          % <-- [Bad] Too deep
          B. Nested item B
          C. Nested item C

2.    ############################
      ############################
          A. Nested item A
          B. Nested item B
          C. Nested item C

3.    ############################
      ############################
      A. Nested item A             % <-- [Good] Pull it back to the left to start at the same starting point of the parent item description
      B. Nested item B
      C. Nested item C
```

Comment: This is all explained in the the `enumitem` documentation. (Check `leftmargin=*`) And now that you have a working sample document, it's better to post that than just the description of what you want.

Comment: I think the downvotes are a little harsh. Yes, given that the OP had asked a previous question, the solution to this one should have been obvious. But as a stand alone question, this is a perfectly reasonable question. One with an obvious answer, sure, but not worthy of downvoting, in my opinion.

Comment: agreed & upvoted;)

Comment: And when OP gets to level 2 or 3, he will start reading docs himself:P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `leftmargin=*` it's on page 4 of the `enumitem` manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[labelsep=2cm]
\item No nested list
\item Nested list:
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item More
  \item Things
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although really, at eleven pages, you probably could have just read the whole `enumitem` manual yourself...